# Riak 2.0.x Link Walkingで一部のデータしか返ってこない

Tags: untagged

riak 2.0.2を使用していて、わからないことができました。

bucketという名前のバケットに、キーがkeyであるオブジェクトを格納し、そこから別のバケットの要素に対してリンクを26個追加しました。

```
curl -v -X GET http://riak-host.hoge.com:8098/buckets/bucket/keys/key
```

このようなリクエストを送ると、レスポンスヘッダのLinkで26個のリンクがあることが確認できました。
しかし、以下のリクエストでLink Walkingを行うと、20個のデータしか返ってきませんでした。

```
curl -v -X GET http://riak-host.hoge.com:8098/buckets/bucket/keys/key/targetbucket,_,1
```

リンク先のオブジェクトが存在しないのでは無いかと思い、確認しましたが、存在していました。
このような場合どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルだけで問題を把握してもらいやすいよう (さらには回答をもらいやすいよう) 編集しました。気に入らないところなどあれば (お手数ですが) [edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Comment: Link を設定したキーのヘッダ情報、「20個のデータしか返ってこなかった」ことをどう確認したのか、Link 先のオブジェクトが "存在していた" ことをどう確認したか、があるとなにか分かるかもしれません。

さらに可能なら再現方法があると情報が出やすくなると思います。ノード数、リングサイズも関係してくるかもしれませんので。

Comment: ご存知かもしれませんが Link Walking は Riak 2.0 で廃止予定リストに入っています。
https://github.com/basho/riak/blob/develop/RELEASE-NOTES.ja.md#%E5%BB%83%E6%AD%A2%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD

Comment: そうなんですね！実は自己解決しまして、riakのクラスタの一部が落ちていました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。riak のクラスタの一部が落ちていたのが原因のようです。

---

この回答は [@syuhei さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1750/riak-2-0-x-link-walking%e3%81%a7%e4%b8%80%e9%83%a8%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%97%e3%81%8b%e8%bf%94%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%93%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment484_1750) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しています。